# Illegal non geometric 'aswkb(...)' value found during parsing

Tags: mysql, gis

I used tutorial from http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/gis-with-mysql.html
so i created two tables, inserted some data and when i tried to get some data using such script

```
SELECT
  c.cab_driver,
  ROUND(GLength(LineStringFromWKB(LineString(AsBinary(c.cab_loc),
                                             AsBinary(a.address_loc)))))
    AS distance
FROM cab c, address a
WHERE a.address = 'Foobar street 110'
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1;
```

i got an error: "Error Code: 1367 Illegal non geometric 'aswkb(`c`.`cab_loc`)' value found during parsing"

Any suggestions?

I've got some progress in this question, i tried to run

```
SELECT 
    asbinary(c.cab_loc)
FROM usercoordinates.cab c;
```

and i am getting NULL in every row but if i use astext i get POINT(...) in every row

Finally i got it, maybe not the best solution but however

```
SELECT
  c.cab_driver,
  Round(glength(LineStringFromWKB(LineString(GeomFromText(astext(c.cab_loc)),GeomFromText(astext(a.address_loc)))))) AS distance
FROM cab c, address a
WHERE a.address = 'Foobar street 99'
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: If you solved your own problem, write an answer and then accept it! That way the next person will be able to find on your solution.

Comment: yea dude, i'm pretty sure I answered this...never accepted my answer, and then posted my answer in question...?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT c.cab_driver,
Round(glength(LineStringFromWKB(LineString(GeomFromText(astext(c.cab_loc)),
GeomFromText(astext(a.address_loc)))))) AS distance
FROM cab c, address a
WHERE a.address = 'Foobar street 99'
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Does it not give the results you need or does it not work at all for your flavor of SQL?

Comment: I meant the sql DID work for me. It returned the expected results as in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Very ugly solution, but I couldn't find another one too.

By the way, we can to shorten query a little by using additional wrap-function:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS pointIt $$
CREATE function pointIt (src POINT)
RETURNS POINT
BEGIN
RETURN GeomFromText(astext(src));
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to make some slight changes of Hituptony's solution for Mysql 5.6:

```
SELECT c.cab_driver,
Round(glength(LineStringFromWKB(LineString(c.cab_loc,
a.address_loc)))) AS distance
FROM cab c, address a
WHERE a.address = 'Foobar street 99'
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1;
```